# HTML tag <a> does not appear in Gmail and Outlook (maybe others)

Tags: templates, outlook, gmail, html-email, mjml

I must repair a bug on the emails sent by my company when a new customer's account is created for the website, it must show a HTML `<a>` tag with the link to go on the new account, but in Gmail and Outlook, this `<a>` tag does not appear.

The code just here:

```
<tr>
  <td style="font-size: 0px; padding: 10px 25px; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px; 
word-break: break-word;" align="center">
    <table style="border-collapse: separate; line-height: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="border: none; border-radius: 37px; cursor: auto; mso-padding-alt: 10px 25px; 
background: #5F9AB0;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5F9AB0"><a href="https://mywebsiteurl.fr" target="blank"> Demander mon mot de passe </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Screenshot of expected result (actual when I read my mail with the Mail mac app)
[image: Screenshot of expected result (actual when I read my mail with the Mail mac app)]

Screenshot of the display of the mail in Chrome and Firefox using Gmail and Outlook webapp

[image: Screenshot of the display of the mail in Chrome and Firefox using Gmail and Outlook webapp]

Comment: Which library do you use? Or framework?

Comment: Please clarify some points here. 'Gmail' = the android app? iOS app? Webmail on which browser? 2. 'Outlook' = windows? Mac? Online? App? And 3: the `<a>` tag does not appear = is it a different colour? Screenshot?

Comment: You have a light blue color on the background where the anchor is sitting in. If its not showing I would say media queries might be causing it to hide/blend into the background

Comment: @Syfer tested without bgcolor but nothing change my <a> tag isn't display

Comment: @Nathan Sorry for the lack of info, when I said Gmail it's fpr the webmail on chrome et firefox browser, same for Outlook. And for the <a> tag just take a look to the first screen where the display is normal (mail mac application) and the second is the bug I said for Gmail and Outlook :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2021/08/2/1614084509-capture-d-ecran-2021-02-23-a-13-48-17.png
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2021/08/2/1614084417-capture-d-ecran-2021-02-23-a-13-46-48.png

Comment: You can add screenshot of the result, otherwise it is very difficult to gain understanding

Comment: It's done @nurgasemetey
And for your question : no use of framework or library, just a mail template with html tag for the display and style

Comment: It is really strange case. Can you just leave `<a>` withou `tr` and `td`?

Comment: @nurgasemetey It's working without `tr` and `td` tag but I don't understand why in a web browser the actual semantic doesn't display my `a` tag

Comment: Maybe it is related with stylesheets applied by Gmail or other mail apps. For positioning you can use `mjml`'s other techniques

Comment: As Syfer said, your `<style>` code might be interfering. Can you paste that in too?

Comment: Ok thanks guys I solved this, I didn't add a font-size so the default display of my <a> tag was "font-size : 0px" ...

Answer (score 0):

@Syfer suggested email queries are involved. If they are, check out https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=media.

That says support for media queries is absent or spotty for all Gmails, all the Outlooks (except for the one that uses Apple Mail), all Yahoo's, all AOL's, and others.

Ain't it grand writing email HTML?